# How to merge GRUB with Windows loader

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub2

My system has Windows 7 pre-installed, I later created a new partition and install Ubuntu 14.04, recently I just install Windows 10 in another partition.

Everything when fine except that GRUB recognize the windows loader instead of each windows version, so if I need to boot into windows 7, I must first choose windows loader from GRUB and then choose windows 7 from windows loader.

Is there anyway can I boot directly into each windows version from the GRUB menu?

Comment: Simple solution: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Can you provide more specific like step-wise solution? I'm already try installing boot repair and use the default fix but grub still taking windows loader.

Comment: "Is there anyway can I boot directly into each windows version from the GRUB menu?"  Once you run Boot Repair, all boot options should be in the same GRUB menu.  It isn't clear what you want that is different.  GRUB is designed to load everything, the Windows loader isn't.